# Suggestion For Finding Similar Rows In Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, soundex

i want select similar rows accourding to row's title columun. Title columun has mostly have 5 or 6 six keywords. Which algorithm do you recommend ? Soundex Maybe ?

P.S: Title columun has unicode chracters like Ç, Ö, Ş...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question's answer mysql full text search. Also it supports unicode.

```
    SELECT *, match(project_title) against('sample project 55') as similarity
    FROM projects
    WHERE status IN(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) AND id != ? AND match('sample project 55') against(?)
    ORDER BY similarity DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean similar in spelling and pronunciation, I'd look into using the [`SOUNDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) function.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'd create a table for `keywords(id, external_id, keyword)`, and then I would join the table against itself, order by how many matches there are, and then grab the rows back out.

If you're matching against a single row, you can select only that one, for much better efficiency with the join.

This could be combined with SOUNDEX to match together things that are close